# IPython Notebook. output in new window

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to get ipython notebook (jupyter) output in new window. Especially this option will be useful with enabled 'nbagg' when you smth plot.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554839/pop-out-expand-jupyter-cell-to-new-browser-window)