# Pop-out / expand jupyter cell to new browser window

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook cell that looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to pop / expand out this to a new browser window (not see the output inline)?

Basically, I want to replicate the `View()` function from R/RStudio... is this possible?

Comment: You can try to use the temporal html files like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977117/ipython-display-full-dataframe-in-new-tab and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439014/possible-for-pandas-dataframe-to-be-rendered-in-a-new-window
Or show the data in other window: Excel, PyQt or tkinter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use Javascript to open a new window, executed by `HTML` from `IPython.display`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
# Show in Jupyter
df

from IPython.display import HTML
s  = '<script type="text/Javascript">'
s += 'var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));'
s += 'win.document.body.innerHTML = \'' + df.to_html().replace("\n",'\\') + '\';'
s += '</script>'

# Show in new Window
HTML(s)
```

Here, `df.to_HTML()` creates a HTML string from the data frame which contains lots of newlines. Those are problematic for Javascript. Multi-line strings in Javascript require a *backslash* at the EOL, that's why python has to modify the HTML string with the `.replace()` method.

What's really cool with JavaScript's `.innerHTML` (instead of `document.write()`) is that you can update your table any time without the need to create a new window:

```
df /= 2
s  = '<script type="text/Javascript">'
s += 'win.document.body.innerHTML = \'' + df.to_html().replace("\n",'\\') + '\';'
s += '</script>'
HTML(s)
```

This will have instant effect on your table in the opened window.

[image]

Here is a simple suggestion of an `View()` emulator from `R` for `python`:

```
def View(df):
    css = """<style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #eee; }
    table tr th:first-child { background-color: #eeeeee; color: #333; font-weight: bold }
    table thead th { background-color: #eee; color: #000; }
    tr, th, td { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 3px; font-family: monospace; font-size: 10px }</style>
    """
    s  = '<script type="text/Javascript">'
    s += 'var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));'
    s += 'win.document.body.innerHTML = \'' + (df.to_html() + css).replace("\n",'\\') + '\';'
    s += '</script>'

    return(HTML(s+css))
```

This works in jupyter simply by typing:

```
View(df)
```

As a fancy topping, it also styles your opened table using some CSS, such that it looks much nicer and comparable to what you know from the `RStudio`.
[image]

Comment: . Just a tip for anyone who wants to implement this: make sure you're not blocking popups on localhost!

Comment: does it only work for Pandas/df or general jupyter cells also- it's in the questions' title

Comment: @alancalvitti You can put almost anything into the [`.innerHTML='...'`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) string and it will display, not only tables.